# Inferring type of lambda expression

Tags: haskell, lambda, types, expression, type-inference

Given a function a with the following type:
    `a :: x -> Bool`
and another function b of the following type:
    `b :: Bool -> y`
I am trying to figure out the steps to infer the type of the following function:
    `c = \d -> d a b`
Could someone please help with help explaining how to do it not just by putting it through ghc's :type function?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the type of `c = \d -> d a b` will be `c :: ((x -> Bool) -> (Bool -> y) -> t) -> t`

Where `d` is a fuction that takes in a `(x -> Bool)` and a `(Bool -> y)` and returns a value of type `t`.

So `c` is a function that takes in function of type `d` and returns a value of type `t`

If you mean `c = \d -> d (a b)` the type will be `c :: (Bool -> y) -> y`

**Some extra explanation.**

To know `c` we must first know what `d`do so we look at `c = \d -> d a b`

We see `\d -> d a b` so we know `d`'s first argument is the function `a` with type `(x -> Bool)`. We also know `d`'s second argument, it is the function `b` with type `(Bool -> y)`. But we don't know what it returns, as this is Haskell it must return something, so I'm just going to write `t` as an unknow type. 
So `d` is `d :: a -> b -> t`.

Substitute in the type of `a` and `b` and we get `d :: (x -> Bool) -> (Bool -> y) -> t`.

Now for `c`, `c` is a lambda that takes in a value we can infer is of type `d`, and returns its output. So we get `c :: d -> (d's output)`.

Substitute in the type of `d` and we get `c :: ((x -> Bool) -> (Bool -> y) -> t) -> t`

Comment: I do mean `c = \d -> d a b`, would you mind explaining a bit more? :)

Comment: I tyred to explain as best I can, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the extra explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach I would take to make sure I am getting the type signature I expect for a particular lambda expression while avoiding `:t` is to use type signatures.

In this case, `x` is unrestricted.

```
idFunction = \x -> x
```

If we want to restrict to a particular type, we can annotate `x` directly. (This requires `:set -XScopedTypeVariables` in GHCi or `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` in a file).

```
idFunction = \(x :: Int) -> x
```

or we can add a type signature

```
idFunction :: Int -> Int
idFunction = \x -> x
```

In your example you only have type signatures, but no function bodies. Let's add some simple function bodies so we can do something with the compiler, then we will try adding a type signature to `c` confirm our belief of what the type should be. We will start with an incorrect type signature.

```
a :: Int -> Bool
a x = x > 0

b :: Bool -> String
b y = show y

c :: ((Bool -> Bool) -> (Bool -> Bool) -> t) -> t
c = \d -> d a b
```

The compiler will find some errors in `c`:

```
<interactive>:10:17: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Bool’ with ‘Int’
      Expected type: Bool -> Bool
        Actual type: Int -> Bool
    • In the first argument of ‘d’, namely ‘a’
      In the expression: d a b
      In the expression: \ d -> d a b

<interactive>:10:19: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Bool’
      Expected type: Bool -> Bool
        Actual type: Bool -> String
    • In the second argument of ‘d’, namely ‘b’
      In the expression: d a b
      In the expression: \ d -> d a b
```

Now if we give `c` the correct type signature it will compile

```
c :: ((Int -> Bool) -> (Bool -> String) -> t) -> t
c = \d -> d a b
```

Generally there isn't any reason to avoid `:t`. It's it perfectly good tool when you are working in GHCi, but when you are building complex functions in a library, you don't necessarily have access to `:t`, so an alternative is to test different type signatures and see how the compiler reacts.

Comment: How would you deal with it if you knew the body functions for a and b where as follows: a = a and b = b

Comment: Those would just be `id` functions, you would have a type signature like `((x -> x) -> (y -> y) -> t) -> t)`.